# define edge set of a graph

Tags: matrix, number-theory, eigenvalues, products, combinatorica

I want to define a graph in Mathematica which its vertex set is cartesian product of two sets. I define the vertex set by Tuple[]
but two vertices are adjacent if and only if the intersection of the first component of two vertices is empty set for example (x,0) is adjacent to (y,1) if and only if x\cap y=empty. I write this

```
 K[n_, k_] := 
 Module[{s = Select[Subsets[Range[n]], Length[#] == k &]}, {B= 
Tuples[{s, {0, 1}}],
{B, matrix = 
 Table[If[Intersection[B[[i]], B[[j]]] == {}, 1, 0], {i, 
   Length[B]}, {j, Length[B]}], 
adjacencygraph = AdjacencyGraph[matrix, VertexLabels ->"Name"]
}}]
```

I don't know how can I get the intersection of two elements in s. my code is wrong because it considers the intersection of two vertices but I want it considers just the first component of two vertices.
I appreciate if anybody can guide me to solve this problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you trying to use `Combinatorica`? What version of Mathematica are you running? Please, edit your post with this latter detail, thanks!

Comment: Please write an *informative* title... one that relates specifically to the content of your question.

Comment: Thank you, I correct it and use tuples but I have another problem with the edge set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`DisjointQ`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DisjointQ.html) + [`RelationGraph`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RelationGraph.html) as follows:

```
ClearAll[relation, rg, nk]

relation = DisjointQ[#[[1]], #2[[1]]] &;

rg[n_, k_, opts : OptionsPattern[]] := RelationGraph[relation, 
   Tuples[{Subsets[Range@n, {k}], {0, 1}}], opts, VertexLabels -> "Name"]

nk[n_, k_, opts : OptionsPattern[]] :=
   {VertexList @ #, MatrixForm @ AdjacencyMatrix @ #, #} & @ rg[n, k, opts]
```

***Examples:***

```
Column @ nk[3, 2]
```

[image]

```
Column @ nk[4, 2]
```

[image]

```
Column @ nk[5, 2]
```

[image]

```
rg[6, 2, ImageSize -> Large, GraphLayout -> "CircularEmbedding"]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, It was very interesting. I learn such thing for the first time. Thank you so much, It was very helpful to me

Comment: @Roya, my pleasure. Welcome to mma.se.